# Failed to insert with: Javascript, Node and MongoDB

Tags: typeorm

After inserting and saving an item in the mongoDB database I get the error:

```
return metadata.objectIdColumn.createValueMap(insertedId);
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createValueMap')
    at MongoDriver.createGeneratedMap (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Proyecto\pruebaORM\api-typeorm\node_modules\typeorm\driver\mongodb\MongoDriver.js:315:40)
    at MongoEntityManager.insert (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Proyecto\pruebaORM\api-typeorm\node_modules\typeorm\entity-manager\MongoEntityManager.js:159:62)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.insertar (C:\Users\USER\Documents\Proyecto\pruebaORM\api-typeorm\database.js:56:3)
```

more information:

- NODEjs v16.13.2
- Lenguaje: JAVASCRIPT.

Schema code:

```
const { EntitySchema } = require('typeorm');
module.exports = new EntitySchema({
    name: 'Usuario',
    columns: {
        _id: {
            primary: true,
            type: "mongodb",
            generated: true,
        },
        nombre: {
            type: 'varchar',
        },
        email: {
            type: 'varchar',
        },
        apellidos: {
            type: 'varchar',
        },
        direccion: {
            type: 'varchar',
        },
        id_puesto: {
            type: 'mongodb',
        },
        id_provincia: {
            type: 'mongodb',
        },
        id_empresa: {
            type: 'mongodb',
        }
    },
    relations: {
        puesto: {
            target: "Puesto",
            type: "many-to-one",
            joinColumn: { name: "id_puesto" }
        },
        provincia: {
            target: "Provincia",
            type: "many-to-one",
            joinColumn: { name: "id_provincia" }
        },
        empresa: {
            target: "Empresa",
            type: "many-to-one",
            joinColumn: { name: "id_empresa" }
        }
    }
});
```

Insert code:

```
async function insertar(model){
  let idPuesto = toObjectId(model.id_puesto);
  let idProvincia = toObjectId(model.id_provincia);
  let idEmpresa = toObjectId(model.id_empresa);
  const user = {
    nombre: model.nombre,
    apellidos: model.apellidos,
    email: model.email,
    direccion: model.direccion,
    id_puesto: idPuesto,
    id_provincia: idProvincia,
    id_empresa: idEmpresa,
  };
  const userRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Usuario);
  await userRepository.insert(user);
}

function toObjectId(value){
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return new ObjectID(value);
  } else {
    return value;
  }
};
```

Save in the database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("646db82a5dbc3b52c5934ada"),
    "nombre" : "Paco Pepe",
    "apellidos" : "Apellido1 Apellido2",
    "email" : "andres@gmail.com",
    "direccion" : "c/cuesta Nº 2",
    "id_puesto" : ObjectId("64368e7dad5d5d509fb797eb"),
    "id_provincia" : ObjectId("64368e2ead5d5d509fb797e9"),
    "id_empresa" : ObjectId("64368e99ad5d5d509fb797ee")
}
```

Can you help me?
Thank you so much

I have tried changing in the schema the type of: 'objectId' to 'mongodb' and varchar without success. Although it saves the data, the application crashes after error.